# Passing the command line parameters to Jetty's start.jar

Tags: java, jetty

I just started working with Jetty in Mac, previously I was using Linux. So now my jetty is installed at

```
/etc/jetty
```

So in order to set the properties like my *deployed.environment*, or *JETTY_HOME* in the configuration file at

```
/etc/jetty/bin/jetty.sh
```

I was using like this

```
JETTY_HOME=/etc/jetty
JETTY_USER=root
JETTY_LOGS=/etc/jetty/logs/
JAVA_OPTIONS+="-Ddeployed.environment=stage -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

But when I came to Mac environment I don't understand where can I give these properties to reflect my environment.

I am looking at a solution by running the Jar with the command line parameters
Please shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance.
:)

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/jetty` concepts found in some Linux distributions are part of that specific distribution's packaging of Jetty.

The Jetty standard distribution does not organize itself in this way.

OSX is also unlikely to organize servers in this way as well.

With Jetty 9.x distribution, you'll unpack that distribution into a directory somewhere, that will become your `${jetty.home}`, then you'll create a new directory with your instance specific configuration (webapps, logs, configuration files, resources, etc) and that will become your `${jetty.base}` directory.

From there its just a matter of configuring your `${jetty.base}/start.ini` and starting up jetty using the `${jetty.home}/start.jar` techniques outlined in the jetty documentation.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the  property I am  looking at is 
deployed.environment which is not mentioned in the doc you shared, also I already have gone through that doc :)

Comment: the property `deployed.environment` is not a property that Jetty itself is aware of, that would be either something custom to your configuration, or something custom that the linux distribution's packaging of Jetty added.